# contact form 7 google goal tracking not working

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, contact-form-7, goal-tracking

i had setup google goal tracking with contact form 7 and it was working earliar.but as on ok sent function deprecated i moved it to function file but now its not working and does not shows any goal in list.Here is my function.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );



    function mycustom_wp_footer() {

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {

        if ( '451' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {

            ga( 'send', 'event','CF7 Form','Submission','cfrom1');



        }

    }, false );

    </script>

    <?php

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The code must be include inside the `jQuery(document).ready()`. The code will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );
function mycustom_wp_footer() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    if ( '451' == event.detail.contactFormId ) {
        ga( 'send', 'event','CF7 Form','Submission','cfrom1');
    }
}, false );
});
</script>

<?php

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Google Analytics Debugger plugin for Chrome (just Google it) is a great tool to tell if your event is triggering correctly.

Also, you might want to check out the Contact Form 7 Google Analytics Intelligence plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-intelligence. It automates event triggers and goal creation in the WordPress admin without having to deal with code.

Answer (score 0):

The goals will appear on report page on Google Analytics 24-48 hours after a submission.

Also, you can check this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-google-analytics/) to setup CF7 submission goals